# Error in apple script

Tags: macos, terminal, applescript

I'm just messing around with apple to script to joke with my friends. I made this simple terminal command to look like their computer is getting hacked (they scare easy). I was going to compile it into an application in apple script, but when I compile it, I keep receive a syntax error. I have tried fixing it, but to no avail. I'm just learning apple script, so this is probably a dumb rookie question. Thanks!
~Cole

Here is the script:

```
tell application "Terminal"
do script "while (true) do echo -n "Error: System Breach Detected    190721064281 killing proccesses. 12060219682197312-90785236412412001-612073412-712481243261=1123-0914712-1209412107381\][12389138719  End."; done"
activate
end tell
```

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to nest a double-quoted string (`"Error: System Breach...`) inside another double-quoted string (`"while (true) do...`), but quotes don't nest. When AppleScript sees `"while (true) do echo -n "Error`, it thinks it's seeing a double-quoted string followed by the word `Error`, which doesn't make any sense.

To fix this, you can escape the inner double-quotes with backslashes (`\`) -- AppleScript will remove the escapes as it parses the string, so they won't get passed to the shell and confuse it. But there's another problem: you also have a stray escape (backslash) in the middle of the string, and that'll also confuse AppleScript. In order to make that work, you actually need to escape the escape (`\\`).  Here's the result of adding the necessary escapes:

```
tell application "Terminal"
    do script "while (true) do echo -n \"Error: System Breach Detected    190721064281 killing proccesses. 12060219682197312-90785236412412001-612073412-712481243261=1123-0914712-1209412107381\\][12389138719  End.\"; done"
    activate
end tell
```